# How to add an image for unit testing?

Tags: images, testing, unit-tests

I have to test the function where it calls `wp_get_attachment_image_src`. How do I add an image for testing, because right now if I call this method it returns false.

Comment: When I've testing suites for WordPress, like any other system, you often need to create mock results for methods that would otherwise hit the database or file system, this is no different.  WordPress itself includes a damn good built in set of tests, so you can trust that most of the code within the cms itself is solid enough for mocks to rely on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd take a look at how WordPress has constructed their attachment tests. You'll find that `tests/phpunit/tests/post/attachments.php` they use [this method](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.5/tests/phpunit/includes/testcase.php#L722):

```
function _make_attachment( $upload, $parent_post_id = 0 ) {

    $type = '';
    if ( !empty($upload['type']) ) {
        $type = $upload['type'];
    } else {
        $mime = wp_check_filetype( $upload['file'] );
        if ($mime)
            $type = $mime['type'];
    }

    $attachment = array(
        'post_title' => basename( $upload['file'] ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_parent' => $parent_post_id,
        'post_mime_type' => $type,
        'guid' => $upload[ 'url' ],
    );

    // Save the data
    $id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload[ 'file' ], $parent_post_id );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $upload['file'] ) );

    return $this->ids[] = $id;

}
```

They've also [included sample images](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/data/images) with their tests. Here is [an example of how they call the `_make_attachment()` method](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.5/tests/phpunit/tests/post/attachments.php#L24) in one of their tests:

```
function test_insert_image_no_thumb() {

    // this image is smaller than the thumbnail size so it won't have one
    $filename = ( DIR_TESTDATA.'/images/test-image.jpg' );
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);

    $upload = wp_upload_bits(basename($filename), null, $contents);
    $this->assertTrue( empty($upload['error']) );

    $id = $this->_make_attachment($upload);

    // ...
```

So you should be able to use something like that to upload an image for your test. You could supply the image to use yourself, or just use one of those already included.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the WordPress testing suite (your test classes extend WP_UnitTestCase), you can use the included factory.

I.e. if your tests are in a `tests` directory you could create `tests/assets/dummy-attachment.jpg`

```
$post = $this->factory->post->create_and_get();
$attachment_id = $this->factory->attachment->create_upload_object( __DIR__ . '/assets/dummy-attachment.jpg', $post->ID );
```